# How do I label the ends of a vector arrow with the coordinates in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Here's a small script to generate a single 2d vector, and I'd like to put the coordinates at either end of the arrow so it is clearer when looking at it.

```
set mxtics 5
set mytics 5
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
plot[y=-10:10][x=-10:10] "file.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors filled head lw 3 notitle
```

and here's my `file.dat`:

```
1 -3 -3 2
```

I've been looking forever and I can't seem to figure out how. This is the first time I'm using gnuplot so it's not coming easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to do this automagically, but here is a workaround.  First I modify the data file to add labels with the coordinates:

```
1 -3 -3 2 "(1,-3)" "(-2,-1)"
```

Then I `plot with labels` and manually adjust the offset to make it look nice:

```
plot[y=-10:10][x=-10:10] 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with vectors filled head lw 3 notitle, \
'' using 1:2:5 with labels offset 3,0, \
'' using 3:4:6 with labels offset 0,-4
```

[image]

Of course, you could skip the fancy plot command and just manually place labels with the coordinates.

Comment: I'm content with adding coordinates manually using labels... but how do I do that?

Comment: `set label X "text" at graph x,y`, where `X` is an optional numerical tag.  You can type `help set label` at the gnuplot console for more info.